# Unable to activate virtual environment in Windows Command Prompt despite it already existing

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I created a virtual environment called 'titanic_datascience' and have been able to use it in the past. However, it no longer activates when I call on it with the command 'workon titanic_datascience'. It claims that it does not exist so I tried to create it again with the command 'mkvirtualenv titanic_datascience', but I get back an error saying it already exists. I called the command 'workon' to double-check if it exists and it confirms that it indeed exists. I finally try to activate it once more with the command 'workon titanic_datascience' but to no avail. I have attached an image of the error.

I am using Windows 10 Command Prompt.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRSVk.png)

I've been googling and looking for similar questions here on stackoverflow, but I have been unable to find anything that resolves the situation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A Python venv typically has a scripts directory containing `activate.bat`. The `workon` command is an extension from `virtualenvwrapper` on top of `virtualenv`. Are you sure that you have virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed correctly?

Comment: I have installed both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-win (I'm using windows).